# How to properly perform data-augmentation on MRI and prepare them for deep learning?

Tags: tensorflow, multidimensional-array, medical, data-augmentation

I'm trying to using deep learning (3D CNN) to perform brain disease classification. Currently, the input size is set to be 96*96*96. This is due to the original scan have a size of 256*256*256. I first removed the background by resizing to 192*192*192 then downsampled by a factor of 2.
However, my dataset only contains 825 subjects. I want to augment the dataset to sufficient size but it troubled me a lot.
First of all, 96^3 result in 884k voxels for input. From my past experience, the number of training samples should be a lot more than the number of input units. So my first question is: **Am I right about the training data should be more than input units** (in this case, more than 884k).
Secondly, to perform data augmentation, **what techniques are recommended**? So far I tried rotation around 3 axes with 10-degree interval. But that only augments the data size by a factor of 100.
Thirdly, when training models, I used to append input data to a list and used sklearn's train-test-split function to split them. Another way is to use keras' ImageDataGenerator.flow_from_directory. However, now I'm dealing with 3D data, and no memory could afford loading thousand of 3d arrays altogether. And ImageDataGenerator does not support nifti file format. **Is there any way I could prepare all my 3d arrays for my training without exhausting my memory?** (I would imagine something like ImageDataGenerator. Of course, this is under my understanding that data generator sends data into the model one batch at a time. Correct me if I'm wrong)

Answer (score 0):

I face the exact same problem on the dataug for MRI so I can't help on that and I'd rather find an answer. However, on the Generator thing, I prepare my dataset BEFORE the training, in another script where I do all the transformation (resize, 3d array preparation, train/test split, ...) and I put everything in 3 big arrays (train, validation and test). I save this array using [Numpy save function](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.save.html). You can also split each array in smaller arrays. If it's still not fitting in your RAM, you can create a sub-class of [Keras Sequence](https://keras.io/utils/#sequence).